# Magento EE 1.12 & SOLR integration issue

Tags: magento-enterprise, solr

I am trying to integrate apache solr with magento enterprise edition version 1.12. Magento 1.12 by default supports solr upto version 3.5. I have tried it with version 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 but i am getting this same error on all versions of SOLR.

Aug 12, 2014 8:57:28 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_en

The complete log is similar to: http://pastie.org/pastes/8154512

I am unable to debug the issue as i am unware of core working of SOLR.

Kindly help.

Comment: Did you contact Magento support for this issue? You may also get an answer here but since you are paying for support you may as well use it :)

Comment: yeah finally got in touch with magento support. I have to send them some details. Once the issue is resolved, i will update the answer here.

Comment: Can you please update the answer ?